# Selected property of Rows Collection set to true doesn't change SelectedRow in DGV

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to implement GlobalKeyPress event that fires on Up and Down arrows, then changes the selected row in DGV - simple, right?

But the following line doesn't change the selected row:

> dgvArtikli.Rows[index++].Selected = true;

What's the catch? There has to be some property or something that I don't know about...

```
private void RegistarMainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            MoveDown();
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            MoveUp();
        }
    }

    private void MoveUp()
    {
        if (dgvArtikli.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (dgvArtikli.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = dgvArtikli.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                dgvArtikli.Rows[index--].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void MoveDown()
    {
        if (dgvArtikli.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (dgvArtikli.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int index = dgvArtikli.SelectedRows[0].Index;
                dgvArtikli.Rows[index++].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the selected row again, then increasing or decreasing index:

- In postfix [increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) operation (index++), the result of the operation is the value of the operand *before* it has been incremented.
- Also in postfix [decrement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx) operation (index--) the result of the operation is the value of the operand *before* it has been decremented.

You can fix this problem by using `++index` and `--index` instead. Also you need better validations for `++` on last row or `--` on first row.

As a better solution, you can can hanlde `ProcessCmdKey` to trap arrow keys <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> even when the `DataGridView` doesn't contain focus.

Then you can use `BindingContext` property of form and find the binding context of `DataGridView` and increase or decrease the `Position` property. The `Position` property takes care of valid ranges for position.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Up)
    {
        BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource, dataGridView1.DataMember].Position -= 1;
        return true;
    }
    if (keyData == Keys.Down)
    {
        BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource, dataGridView1.DataMember].Position += 1;
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks both of your solutions work, I think I'm gonna use ProcessCmdKey override: that's the exactly what I needed, to be able to switch selectedRows even when my DGV doesn't have focus!